# How to connect my Xcode project to a remote repository that doesn't yet exist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, github

I have an Xcode project that has a local repository. I've successfully used add, commit and push, and now I want to connect to a remote repository so that my project appears online on GitHub. However, I don't have an existing repository. How can I create a repository and then connect it my local repository through (1) Xcode or (2) git commands in Terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it inside Xcode pretty easily.

1. Go to the Source Control navigator (the second icon at the top of the Project Navigator)
2. Expand the disclosure arrow until you see the "Remotes" folder
3. Right-click on the "Remotes" folder
4. Select <kbd>New "MyProject" Remote...</kbd>
5. Follow the instructions, then click <kbd>Create</kbd>. That's it!

| Steps 1-4 | Step 5 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Steps 1-4] | [image: Create "MyProject" remote: text fields and buttons, including Account, Owner, Repository name, Description, Visibility (Public or Private), and Remote Name (default is "origin"). Click Create to finish.] |